# Django filter date not format correctly

Tags: django, date, datetime

Using the Django date filter

```
{{ post.created_at|date:"d F y - h:i A" }}
```

some of the parameters are not correctly formatted and i get

```
9 F 2015 - 2:i A
```

So seems like the F, i and A does not get parsed correctly.
Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Do you have localization enabled in your project? That could affect the `date` format. See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/

Comment: I dont think `i` is a valid formatter. Did you try `d F y - h:I A` ?

Comment: according to this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date

both i and F are valid formatter

Comment: @karthikr `i` is for minutes.

Comment: @xyres yes the localization is enabled and even disabling it, i get the same output

Comment: @DavePlug Hmm.. Strange. I tested your code and it works just fine.

Comment: im using django 1.9 on mac, what version are you using?

Comment: @DavePlug I am using version 1.8

Comment: @DavePlug Can you try this code: `{% localize off %}{{ post.created_at|date:"d F y - h:i A" }}{% endlocalize %}` and see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was not caused by the Django |date filter but by the angular |date filter that for some reason was being executed.

Fixed, and sorry for all the good peoples that helped me out!